# JAVA- copy duplicates from one text file to another- need help removing multiple copies in output

Tags: java, duplicates, text-files

So i can't use arrayList or hash yet as we haven't learned it. I have successfully copied only the duplicates to the new text file.. now I can't figure out how to only copy the one duplicate instead of all of them into the new file. The output I want is:
Animal Crossing
Java Foundations
Web Programming
Snowboarding 101
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HYJY.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    boolean flag = false;


   String input = ("C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\COMP1231\\"
            + "Assignment 3\\BookTitles.inp");
    String output = "C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\COMP1231\\"
            + "Assignment 3\\DuplicatesBook.inp";
    
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
        
        String s;
        
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        bw.write(s + "\n");
        flag = false;
        
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(output));
        String s2;
        
        while((s2 = br2.readLine()) != null){
            if (s.equals(s2)){
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            s2 = br2.readLine();
        }
        
        if (!flag){
           bw.write(s + "\n");
            bw.flush();
        }
         s = br.readLine();
    }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Files successful.");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }
    
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about arrays, can you use them?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I tried a different way, by using `ArrayList<String>` to look for duplicate lines. The code searches for duplicate lines and writes them to the output file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String input = ("C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\COMP1231\\"
            + "Assignment 3\\BookTitles.inp");
    String output = "C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\COMP1231\\"
            + "Assignment 3\\DuplicatesBook.inp";
    
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
        
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(s);
        }
        
        for(String main : lines) {
            if(duplicates.contains(main)) {
                // Skip this line, because we already figured out that it's duplicate
                continue;
            }
            int count = 0;
            for(String sub : lines) {
                if(sub.equals(main)) {
                    // The lines are equal
                    // increase the counter
                    count++;
                }
            } 
            // If the line appears more then once
            // Add it to the duplicate list
            if(count > 1) {
                duplicates.add(main);
            }
        }
        
        // Write all duplicate lines to the BufferedOutputWriter
        for(String duplicate : duplicates) {
            bw.write(duplicate+"\n");
        }
        
        // Don't forget to flush..
        bw.flush();
        
        // Close all inputs and outputs
        bw.close();
        br.close();
        
        System.out.println("All files saved.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```